# how to use "pragma omp task" inside a VS CUDA project?

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2017, openmp

in a VS CUDA project, I want to use `#pragma omp task`

if i wanted to use this pragma inside a non-CUDA project, I would have just switched to Intel compiler which supports it, but it cause problem in CUDA ones, returning "invalid preprocessor command 'include_next" error in compilation time

and if I don't, traditional VS compiler, or in this case nvcc, won't support this pragma

Comment: If you have the option, you may want to ditch OpenMP alltogether, it's pretty much EOL and support is dwindling. C++17 parallel features, or Intels TBB is essentially the way to go.

Comment: @Ext3h it's an university project and i should use both

Comment: The Visual studio compiler doesn't support OpenMP 3/4 features

Comment: @talonmies i know, and that's why i switch to Intel compiler when i want to work with tasks, but Intel compiler cannot work with CUDA, so how can i use OpenMP v3 features with CUDA??

Comment: You can't, or at least you can't in Windows. The Visual C++ compiler is the only supported compiler on Windows platforms. Linux supports compilers which implement OpenMP 4